# recvfrom() socket is not working after this function

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel

I am facing issue with calling to `recvfrom` function:

```
recvfrom(sock, dat, sizeof(dat), 0, (void *)&peername, &peernamelen);
```

Until this all functions are working.
Please let me know where I am making mistake. Should I use bind or not, or any mistake from this.

Output:

```
        before sockname
        after sockname
        after sock
        after setsockopt
        after Bind
        before recvfrom
```

My code:

```
   struct sockaddr_can sockname = { 
        .can_family = AF_CAN,
        .can_addr.j1939 = { 
            .addr = J1939_NO_ADDR,
            .name = J1939_NO_NAME,
            .pgn = J1939_NO_PGN,
        },
    }, peername = { 
        .can_family = AF_CAN,
        .can_addr.j1939 = { 
            .addr = J1939_NO_ADDR,
            .name = J1939_NO_NAME,
            .pgn = J1939_NO_PGN,
        },
    };  
    uint8_t dat[128];
    int valid_peername = 0;
    unsigned int todo_send = 0;
    int todo_recv = 0, todo_echo = 0, todo_prio = -1; 
    int todo_connect = 0, todo_names = 0, todo_wait = 0, todo_rebind = 0;
    int todo_broadcast = 0, todo_promisc = 0;
    int no_bind = 0,i;
    printf("before sockname\n");
    sockname.can_ifindex = if_nametoindex(CAN_SOCKET_NAME);
    printf("after sockname\n");
    sock = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_J1939);
    printf("after sock\n");
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &todo_broadcast, sizeof(todo_broadcast));
    printf("after setsockopt\n");
    ret = bind(sock, (void *)&sockname, sizeof(sockname));
         if (ret < 0)
             err(1, "bind()");
    printf("after Bind\n");
    while(1){
        peernamelen = sizeof(peername);
        printf("before recvfrom\n");
        recvfrom(sock, dat, sizeof(dat), 0, (void *)&peername, &peernamelen);
        printf("%02x %05x:", peername.can_addr.j1939.addr, peername.can_addr.j1939.pgn);
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < ret; ++i, j++) {
            if (j == 8) {
                printf("\n%05x    ", i); 
                j = 0;
            }
            printf(" %02x", dat[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: *"facing issue"* and *"not working"* are not useful error descriptions. Basically this is a code dump without information of what it is supposed to do, without any useful comments and without error checking and reporting on the place you have problems with.

Comment: you are not checking the return value of `socket()`, `setsockopt()` or `recvfrom()` for success/failure. You are only checking `bind()`.